# How do you reference an API and use it as data in D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I want to make a bar chart using an API that pulls a JSON, but am not sure how to go about referencing the data.

First point of data is a name that is supposed to be the category, and the second is the actual data value that the bar will use to determine its height. For example:

Ralph 92
Jim 34
Michelle 55

```
var Champs;
function callback(response) {
Champs = response;
console.log(Champs);
}

var url = 
"https://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/4.7.16/data/en_US/champion.json";

d3.json(url, function(data) {
callback(data);

Object.keys(Champs.data).forEach(function(key, index) {
  var champsObj = key;
  var champName = Champs.data[champsObj].name;
  var champHP = Champs.data[champsObj].stats.hp;
})

  var scale = d3.scaleLinear()
      .domain([0, d3.max(data.data, function(d){ return d.data.stats.hp})])
      .range([0, 500]);

  var canvas = d3.select('body').append('svg')
      .attr('width', 500)
      .attr('height', 500)


  canvas.selectAll('rect')
    .data(data.data)
    .enter()
      .append('rect')
      .attr('width', function(d){return scale(d.data.stats.hp)})
      .attr('height', 6)
      .attr('y', function(d, i){return i*7})
      .attr('fill', 'blue')

});
```

I searched through the documentation as well as a d3wiki for the answers, and found a bit of help from a similar question here but I'm still really struggling with how to reference the data in the json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`data.data` here is not an array but an object, call `Object.values(data.data)` to get the array with the values.

```
function callback(response) {
    Champs = response;
    console.log(Champs);
}

var url = 
"https://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/4.7.16/data/en_US/champion.json";

d3.json(url, function(data) {
callback(data);

  var scale = d3.scaleLinear()
      .domain([0, d3.max(Object.values(data.data), function(d){ return d.stats.hp})])
      .range([0, 500]);

  var canvas = d3.select('body').append('svg')
      .attr('width', 500)
      .attr('height', 500)


  canvas.selectAll('rect')
    .data(Object.values(data.data))
    .enter()
      .append('rect')
      .attr('width', function(d){return scale(d.stats.hp)})
      .attr('height', 6)
      .attr('y', function(d, i){return i*7})
      .attr('fill', 'blue')

});
```

Comment: Ahh thank you so much! If I might ask how would I get labels beside each bar using the .id value?

Comment: @Hawke just like the above, `canvas.selectAll('text').data(Object.values(data.data)).enter().append('text').text(function(d) {return d.id})`